# Is it possible to change stylesheet URI on production build (webpack / craco)?

Tags: reactjs, webpack, build, production, craco

when building react app for production build, I would want to change specific stylesheet link from "http://127.0.0.1:4000/custom/styles.css"  to "/custom/styles.css"

Is it possible to do that with webpack / craco ?
If it's possible how can I achieve this? :)

Comment: Where do you have such link?

Comment: In index.html file

Comment: why aren't you importing it with relative link? `import './custom/style.css`? https://create-react-app.dev/docs/adding-a-stylesheet/

Comment: It is complicated thing, but image something like this -> when react.js is run on development server it will be working on port :3000 and when I will try to access it by /custom/styles.css It will point to 127.0.0.1:3000/custom/styles.css but when I will create production build it will point to 127.0.0.1:4000/custom/styles.css and it will work only in production environment. I need to make it to work both on production and in development environments. React build is served from back-end as static files...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you use Create React App you can utilize  [dotenv variables](https://create-react-app.dev/docs/adding-custom-environment-variables/).

At the root directory create files `.env` and `.env.development`, properties should be like:

```
REACT_APP_STYLESHEET_URI=somevalue
```

where `somevalue` can have any value and be different on dev/production.

You can access them in code via:

```js
const uri = process.env.REACT_APP_STYLESHEET_URI
```

Or in `index.html`:

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="%REACT_APP_STYLESHEET_URI%">
```

Comment: I know about environment variables but the thing is that stylesheet URI value is index.html and I cannot just hard-code  environment variable in html document.

I need to utilize craco / webpack to replace the URI value...

Comment: https://create-react-app.dev/docs/adding-custom-environment-variables/#referencing-environment-variables-in-the-html

Comment: Updated answer to add this detail @LuckyLuke

Comment: It does work, the environment variable stuff. When build production build the URI is correct but when trying to start in development server the environment variable is not inserted in URI. Thus I have created .env.development file..

Comment: You need to restart a running dev server, changes in .env are only picked up on server startup